# value of rolling password generators

Tags: authentication, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, prime-factoring

Several products like google Authenticator and RSA will display periodic numerical values to authenticate users into a system.

[image]

How do the changing numerical values make it more secure?

Is the premise that no one is likely to reverse factor a 256 bit private key in 10 (or X) seconds? Because doesn't that take more like decades/centuries?

Suppose they are able to reverse factor it in an hour while I am still having my authenticated session. If there was a man-in-the-middle, what has expired that would make him less able to reverse the encryption?

Or is it just that the numbers aren't visible in the screen anymore?

Comment: It relies on a separate path to communicate  extra information to you that no one else can see. So even if they (naughty people) have some of your details they cannot look like you when they try and login. It assumes that you have the hardware and no else can see the display. So, when you enter the full signon details that includes the values from the hardware display then it must be from you only. (see `two factor authorization`) If the lifetime is short then it is assumed to be secure. It is mormally.

Comment: Google Authenticator doesn't use RSA at all. It's all based on a shared secret, current time/counter, and HMAC. http://security.stackexchange.com/q/35157/45523

Comment: @ArtjomB.: interesting, thanks. I'm assuming they're both asymmetric and involve counters.